# Double Value (abreast) in Listbox between another page (Session) . I Need Text + Value in Listbox between Pages (variable Session)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, listbox, listboxitem

## Hello All,

Pleas, i have small Problem. There are 2 Pages . In One Page through Button1 Add Text and Value ("123456", "Jan Novak") to Listbox. I need These both value from Listbox in another Pages transfer. When i have only 1 Value, it's no Problem, but with 2 Value a have after  "Double" abreast in Listbox.

There is my Code.

```
Default.aspx

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Session"] != null)
            {

                ListItemCollection hodnotyState = (ListItemCollection)Session["Session"];

                foreach (ListItem i in hodnotyState)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(i.Text + "|" + i.Value);

                }
                Session.Clear();
            }

        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("123456","Jan Novak"));
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItemCollection kolekce = new ListItemCollection();

            foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
            {

                kolekce.Add(i.Text + "|" + i.Value);

                Session["Session"] = kolekce;
            }
            Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");

    }
}
```

page2.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public partial class page2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Session"] != null)
            {

                ListItemCollection hodnotyState = (ListItemCollection)Session["Session"];

                foreach (ListItem i in hodnotyState)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(i.Text + "|" + i.Value);

                }
                Session.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("987654","John Smith"));
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItemCollection kolekce = new ListItemCollection();


        Session.Clear();
            foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
            {

                kolekce.Add(i.Text + "|" + i.Value);

                Session["Session"] = kolekce;
            }
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

    }
}
```

Otherwise these Text + Values is not below in Listbox, but "abreast".
Have someone better Experience?
Thank you All.

Comment: This is .net, not Classic ASP

Comment: Sorry, I am Idiot ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add them in the way you want them displayed, instead of trying to do it after the fact?

Default.aspx functions:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Session"] != null)
            {
                ListItemCollection hodnotyState = (ListItemCollection)Session["Session"];

                foreach (ListItem i in hodnotyState)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(i);
                }
                Session.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem newItem = new ListItem("123456", "Jan Novak");
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(newItem.Text + newItem.Value, newItem.Value));
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItemCollection kolekce = new ListItemCollection();

        foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            kolekce.Add(i);
        }
        Session["Session"] = kolekce;

        Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
    }
}
```

And page2.aspx functions:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Session"] != null)
            {
                ListItemCollection hodnotyState = (ListItemCollection)Session["Session"];

                foreach (ListItem i in hodnotyState)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(i);
                }
                Session.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem newItem = new ListItem("987654", "John Smith");
        ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(newItem.Text+newItem.Value, newItem.Value));
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItemCollection kolekce = new ListItemCollection();
        Session.Clear();
        foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            kolekce.Add(i);
        }
        Session["Session"] = kolekce;

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer, these Text + Values are abreast..I Changed Code,but no Result :-(

Comment: @Messiah1985 What do you want the ListBox to look like?  Do you want each item to show "John Smith", "987654", or "987654 John Smith"?

Comment: @Messiah1985 I've updated my answer, but I'm still not sure it's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you glue together the Text and Value into a single string in this line: `kolekce.Add(i.Text + i.Value)`.

You have two options:
1) use a different collection where you store a KeyValuePair, so you can keep "key" and "value" apart

2) Add the values together into a single string (as you are doing now), but with a separator (`kolekce.Add(i.Text + "|" + i.Value)`). When you read back that collection, split on that separator to get a separate key and value.

In both cases, don't add a single string to your ListBox1, but a new `ListItem` with separate key and value.

Example:

If you store the list like this:

```
StringCollection kolekce = new StringCollection();
foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
{
    kolekce.Add(i.Text + "|" + i.Value);
}
Session["Session"] = kolekce;
```

(note: store in the session *after* the foreach-loop, once is enough)
then you need this to read it back:

```
if (Session["Session"] != null)
{
     StringCollection hodnotyState = (StringCollection)Session["Session"];

     foreach (string s in hodnotyState)
     {
         string[] sa = s.Split('|');
         ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(sa[0], sa[1]);
     }
     Session.Remove("Session");
}
```

Comment: Could you pleas there write a short Example pleas ? I tried something write, but always no results. :-( (I edited my Code above)

Comment: @Messiah1985 - see the answer by jadarnel27 for an example of option 1.

Comment: @Messiah1985 - added an example of option 2